# How to redirect to another page with context, after posting a form?

Tags: python, django

After posting my form, I want to redirect to another page and send some data to that page with context. I need to send a string and boolean value to the other page, depending if the post to the database was successful or not.

With the view I have, the admin.html is rendered but the url is not updated (it still shows the form page). How can I achieve this

I've tried to play around with the redirect.
    return redirect(reverse('app:view', kwargs={ 'bar': FooBar }))
But no luck yet.

```
def report_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            report_title = form.cleaned_data['report_title']
            report_link = form.cleaned_data['report_link']
            new_report = Report(title = report_title, link = 
report_link)
            new_report.save()
            return render(request, 'dashboard/admin.html', {'title': 
Admin Page, 'added':True})
```

Comment: "I need to send a string and boolean value to the other page, depending if the post to the database was successful or not." => if the goal is to display a success message you possibly want to have a look at the `messages` framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes I want to display a message with the two parameters I'll send.

Comment: Then just use the messages framework, that's __exactly__ what it's for.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass context with redirect,although you can pass as url parameters:

```
redirect(reverse('app:admin', kwargs={ 'title': 'title','added':True }))
```

If you want to render context,you can write two views:

Forexample :

```
def view1(request, newContext=None) : 
 ..
 ..
 context = {
 ..
 }
 context.update(newContext)
 ..
 return render(request, "../../xyz.html", context=context)
def view2(request) : 
 ..
 context = {
 ..
 }
 ..
 response = view1(request, context)
 return response
```

Comment: Don't use an empty container as default value, cf https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments